# How do I use method in this script?

Tags: ruby, variables, methods, cucumber

I am using ruby-cucumber for automation. The steps are as follows:

```
Then    I click on "Add this" link
Then    I click on "Next" link
```

This is the script:

```
Then(/^I click on "Add this" link$/) do
  @driver.find_element(:link, "Add this").click
end
```

How should I modify the code so that I can use it both for "Add this" & "Next" repeatedly? Any help/comments is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Then(/^I click on "([^"]*)" link$/) do |link|
  @driver.find_element(:link, link).click
end
```

This will then match anything e.g.

```
Then    I click on "Add this" link
Then    I click on "Next" link
Then    I click on "Foobar" link
```